# kill or get state of process within chroot jail

Tags: c, process, kill-process, chroot

I was wondering if it was possible to use the `kill` function in `C` to check if a process id exists within a `chroot` jail. I know that you can use the `kill` function to check if a process exists, with the signal set to `0`; but that only provides access towards the process within the current context - being the host system. My issue is that I have a process running within the `chroot` jail which needs to have it's state checked, in this case the process id of that running process will always be the same number: *5*; but with the `kill` function only checking for the process in the host system's context, it always seems to exists, as another process outside of the `chroot` jail has the same process id. My question is, is it possible to check the state within the `chroot` jail, without having to create a local `proc` directory (as the chroot process within cannot have a `proc` directory - due to the scope of the projects limit size and aim for embedded devices).

I've literally found nothing on this subject. So I am unable to provide any contributions towards this, sorry about that folks... However, any help, or expertise in this area would help massively!

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: is it a 'c' question or a linux question? i would recommend asking it on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @effenok this is a C question, as the function calls are within the C language, and not as executable commands.